# Octave eigs() function bugged?

Tags: octave, numerical-methods, eigenvalue

Running Octave 6.3.0 for Windows. I need to get the smallest eigenvalue of some matrix.`eigs(A,1,"sm")` is supposed to do that, but I often get wrong results with singular matrices.

`eigs(A)` (which returns <s>all the</s> the first 6 eigenvalues/vectors) is correct (at least at the machine precision):

```
>> A = [[1 1 1];[1 1 1];[1 1 1]]
A =

   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1

>> [v lambda flag] = eigs(A)
v =

   0.5774  -0.3094  -0.7556
   0.5774  -0.4996   0.6458
   0.5774   0.8091   0.1098

lambda =

Diagonal Matrix

   3.0000e+00            0            0
            0  -4.5198e-16            0
            0            0  -1.5831e-17

flag = 0
```

But `eigs(A,1,"sm")` is not:

```
>> [v lambda flag] = eigs(A,1,"sm")
warning: eigs: 'A - sigma*B' is singular, indicating sigma is exactly an eigenvalue so convergence is not guaranteed
warning: called from
    eigs at line 298 column 20

warning: matrix singular to machine precision
warning: called from
    eigs at line 298 column 20

warning: matrix singular to machine precision
warning: called from
    eigs at line 298 column 20

warning: matrix singular to machine precision
warning: called from
    eigs at line 298 column 20

warning: matrix singular to machine precision
warning: called from
    eigs at line 298 column 20

v =

  -0.7554
   0.2745
   0.5950

lambda = 0.4322
flag = 0
```

Not only the returned eigenvalue is wrong, but the returned flag is zero, indicating that every went right in the function...

Is it a wrong usage of eigs() (but from the doc I can't see what is wrong) or a bug?

EDIT: if not a bug, at least a design issue... No problem either when requesting the 2 smallest values instead of the smallest value alone.

```
>> eigs(A,2,"sm")
ans =

  -1.7700e-17
  -5.8485e-16
```

EDIT 2: the eigs() function in Matlab online just runs fine and return the correct results (at the machine precision)

```
>> A=ones(3)

A =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1

>> [v lambda flag] = eigs(A,1,"smallestabs")

v =

   -0.7556
    0.6458
    0.1098


lambda =

  -1.5831e-17


flag =

     0
```

Comment: " I often get wrong results with singular matrices".... Yeah? Almost the definition of singular matrices. Eigenvalues of singular matrices are zero. And singular matrices screw up numerical computation hard. Welcome to the world of numerical computing.

Comment: I guess if I were to write the code in Octave, I'd make the flag 1 for detected singular matrices, but not sure if a bug or a design choice. In some way, you should know better than try to compute eigenvalues of singular matrices

Comment: You also get a pretty clear warning: “warning: eigs: 'A - sigma*B' is singular, indicating sigma is exactly an eigenvalue so convergence is not guaranteed”. Not sure what else you expect…

Comment: @AnderBiguri: "Eigenvalues of singular matrices are zero"... indeed, and that's why I am expecting eigs() to return zero (to the machine precision) as the smallest magnitude eigenvalue in this case. Maybe the algorithm used by eigs() is not valid for singular matrices, and I could understand that, but:

Comment: Yeah, but welcome to the world of numerical computing. If numerical computing could solve accruately all math, the world would be such a more advance place.

Comment: (my last comment was not complete...)
...but:
- it is not stated in the documentation
- the return status (flag) is zero as if it was OK
- eigs() called with a single argument (the matrix) correctly computes all the eigenvalues, even the ones that are zero.

Comment: @CrisLuengo:  such a warning message is not really useful in a code where eigs() is repeatedly called. How to know which calls are OK and which ones are not? What is needed here is a return status that can be tested within a code. Besides, this does not explain why ```eigs(A)``` can return the right results...

Comment: You need to check the matrix for singularity before attempting to compute eigenvalues. Sure Octave could return a proper error code, but it doesn't. So it is up to you to validate the matrix first. `eigs(A,2,"sm")` and `eigs(A)` are two totally different algorithms. Besides, `eigs(A)` here doesn't return the right results, two eigenvalues should be identical to 0.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I can live with approximate results at the machine precision (-1.77e-17 instead of 0 is OK). Testing if the matrix is singular is not enough in my case, as I actually need the eigenvector associated to the smallest eigenvalue... At the moment I am just calculating all the eigenvalues with eig() and pick the smallest one.

Comment: The smallest eigenvector is 0, thus the corresponding vector is meaningless. You **cannot** do eigen analysis of a singular matrix. The vector you get is determined by floating-point rounding errors.

Comment: I have to disagree here. The eigenvectors associated to null eigenvalues are defined and meaningful, all the same than for any other eigenvalue. BTW the eigenvectors returned by ```eigs(A)``` in my original text are correct, _at the machine precision_.

The problem here is not that the input matrix is singular. You can also try by yourself ```eigs([[5 0 0];[0 3 0];[0 0 1]],1,1)``` which displays the same warning message about singularity and gives a wrong result, although the input matrix is definitely not singular.

Comment: Rule of thumb: mature software runs fine and those claiming "bugs" are wrong.

Comment: Returning a wrong result and a "it's OK" status is not exactly what I call "running fine". The flag argument should not be returned with a zero value in the cases I am describing.

Comment: I could test the eigs() function of Matlab Online, and it gives the right results in all cases (I have edited my initial message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more tests and investigations I think I can answer that yes, Octave eigs() has some flaw.

`eigs(A,1,"sm")` likely uses the inverse power iteration method, that is repeatedly solving y=A\x, then x=y, starting with an arbitrary x vector. Obviously there's a problem if A is singular. However:

- Matlab eigs() runs fine in such case, and returns the correct eigenvalue (at the machine precision). I don't know what it does, maybe adding a tiny value on the diagonal if the matrix is detected as singular, but it does something better (or at least different) than Octave.
- If for some (good or bad) reason Octave's algorithm cannot handle a singular matrix, then this should be reflected in the 3rd return argument ("flag"). Instead, it is always zero as if everything went OK.

`eigs(A,1,"sm")` is actually equivalent to `eigs(A,1,0)`, and the more general syntax is `eigs(A,1,sigma)`, which means "find the closest eigenvalue to sigma, and the associated eigenvector". For this, the inverse power iteration method is applied with the matrix `A-sigma*I`. Problem: if sigma is already an exact eigenvalue this matrix is singular by definition. Octave eigs() fails in this case, while Matlab eigs() succeeds. It's kind of weird to have a failure when one knows in advance the exact eigenvalue, or sets it by chance. So the right thing to do in Octave is to test if `(A-sigma.I)` is singular, and if yes add a tiny value to sigma: `eigs(A,1,sigma+eps*norm(A))`. Matlab eigs() probably does something like that.